# Django DRF - API shows json format instead of interface

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I recently updated to Django 4.0 and DRF 3.13.1, and now my API shows in json format by default, whereas before it was showing the interface.

I would like to see an interface like so:

[image]

But this is what I now get.

[image]

Is there a way to change this back to the interface?
Sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer', # add this first.
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a quick solution, you could also just change the path variable: "format" in the url directly.

When we click on the JSON button, a path variable is sent like this:

> http://localhost:8000/collections?format=json

You could change it to:

> http://localhost:8000/collections?format=api

or you could just remove it given that "api" is the default value:

> http://localhost:8000/collections

Hope this helps.